# Prolog program about lists

Tags: prolog

I am a new programmer in Prolog and i tried to do a program that says: make the predicate `penta(X)`, where `X` is a list and returns `true` when in `X` there are 5 consecutive elements where : the first element is the sum between the first and the second. Also the third element is the difference between the 5th and the 4th for example: `X = [ ... 5, 7, 12, 18, 30, ... ]`.

So I did this:

```
penta(X) :-
\+length(X,0),   //here i verify if the lists contains less than 5 elements so it gives false.
\+length(X,1),
\+length(X,2),
\+length(X,3),
\+length(X,4),
(A, B, C, D, E | X),
C is A + B,
C is D - E,
penta(X).
```

This actually does not compile so it doesn't work yet. Tell me what's wrong with it if you would like.

thank you very much.

Comment: I presume you get some kind of error message when it "does not compile"; you might want to read that.

Comment: @ScottHunter it says: uncought error(existence_error(procedure,('|')/2),penta/1

Comment: @ScottHunter oh sorry! it compiles now but it still gives this error i wrote before

Comment: What does `(A, B, C, D, E | X)` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In prolog, we write *predicates* not *functions*. A predicate defines a rule which will succeed or fail on sets of instantiated variables. So you want a predicate, `penta(X)` that succeeds if `X` is a list that contains 5 consecutive elements meeting your criteria.

Start from the top. Either the 5 consecutive elements that meet the criteria are at the head of your list, or they are later in the list.

```
% Succeed if the first 5 elements meets the criteria
penta([A, B, C, D, E |_]) :-
    ... % what goes here for this to succeed?

% Succeeds if the rest of the list succeeds, without the first element
penta([_|T]) :- penta(T).
```

I think these are the only two rules you need. Anything else you query that doesn't match these will fail by default, which is what you want. You don't need to check for the length for the 0 through 4 length cases. Those cases will fail the above predicates.

You'll notice that, depending upon how you implement the above, it might succeed several times. That is, it may find more than one solution. You need to decide if that's what you want, or if you want it to stop after one solution. I'll leave that as further exercise.